# Asp .Net Identity - Custom IUserStore FindByNameAsync method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I want to override `IUserStore` `FindByNameAsync` method. Method is used in `CreateAsync` method of `UserManager` class. If I return `IdentityUser` instance from the method, it works fine, but if I return `null` (e.g. there is no user with that username) I got:

> {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.","ExceptionType":"System.NullReferenceException","StackTrace":"   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserValidator`2. ValidateUserName d__4.MoveNext()

This is my override method

```
public Task<MyUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
{
    return null;
}
```

I think it fails in `UserValidator` class - `ValidateUserName` method in code snippet below.

```
else
{
    var owner = await Manager.FindByNameAsync(user.UserName).WithCurrentCulture();
    if (owner != null && !EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default.Equals(owner.Id, user.Id))
    {
        errors.Add(String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, Resources.DuplicateName, user.UserName));
    }
}
```

What to return from `FindByNameAsync` method to avoid this exception?

Comment: Default implementation used Asp .Net Identity EntityFramework implementation. It could be found here https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/UserStore.cs. In my implementation I do not use EF or LINQ, I just return null.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to still return a Task in your code, see the change below. This is because the callers expects a Task and the result in the Task is what you want to return as having a `null` value. By returning `null` directly the caller's attempt to unwrap the task (through `await` or `Task.Result`) fails which generates the `NullReferenceException`.

```
public Task<MyUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
{
    return Task.FromResult((MyUser)null);
}
```